# JavaScript Function that creates 4 random numbers that push to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

Instead of doing this:

```
var crystalValues = [];
crystalValues[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1),
crystalValues[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1),
crystalValues[2] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1),
crystalValues[3] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1),
```

How can I create a function that returns 4 random numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The function below creates an array of random ints.

The `count` sets how many, `min` and `max` set the min and max random values

```js
    function createRandomArray(count,min,max){
        const rand = () =>  Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        const vals = [];
        while(count-- > 0){ vals.push(rand()) }
        return vals;
    }
    console.log(createRandomArray(4,1,13));
```

You can assign them to another array as follows

```
const crystalValues = [];
crystalValues.push(...createRandomArray(4,1,13))
```

Or just directly assign them

```
const crystalValues = createRandomArray(4,1,13);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

Try this:

```
var crystalValues = [];

for(var i = 0;i < 4;i++){
  crystalValues.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1))
}

console.log(crystalValues);
```

Comment: How can I make sure these numbers never equal each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
var gen = () => {
 return Array.from({length: 4}, () => Math.floor( Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1)));
}

console.log(gen());
```

Comment: How can I make sure these numbers never equal each other?

Answer (score 0):

A for loop would do the trick if you're trying to save time typing the function out.

```
random4() {
    var crystalValues = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 4 ; i++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
        while (crystalValues.indexOf(randomNumber) !== -1) {
            randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
        }
        crystalValues[i] = randomNumber;
    }
    return crystalValues;
}
```

Comment: How can I make sure these numbers never equal each other?

Comment: I edited my code to show you:
add a while loop checking for the index of the new random number until you get a unique one. Just make sure that if you change the code, you dont end up with an infinite loop